# python calculation of tuples of two for big n

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, combinations, dask

I'm trying to calculate all possible combinations of pairs in tuples starting from 0 to the length of my file (62977) so i get this result as a single DASK series\data frame with no duplicates:

```
(0,1), (0,2), (0,3) ...(0,62976),(1,2), (1,3), ... (62975,62976)
```

How can I do this without having memory errors?

Please help, I don't have any more solutions :(

Comment: if you don't need to keep them all at once, use iterator/generator

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I need to keep them all at once to add them to another dask data frame I have

Comment: well, there are 1,982,956,800 such combinations, i.e. 62976 choose 2 (`import math; print(math.comb(62976, 2))` If each of those must be a tuple, then you would need like 56*math.comb(62976, 2) bytes which is like 111 gigabytes

Comment: @MikaBell If you "...need to keep them all at once..." then you'll just need lots of RAM. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here (or why this has to be a DASK series)...
if you intend to iterate over the list, [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) might be what you're looking for

It'll return a generator so no memory issues but be aware that there are quite a few combinations possible... (1982956800 to be exact)

```py
from itertools import combinations

x = range(62976)
combs = combinations(x, 2)

for c in combs:
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to add this dask series to another dask data frame i have in order to keep track of calculations I've made of pairs, how can i turn 'combinations' here into dask series?

Comment: without a minimal working example of what you are actually trying to do here, it's kinda impossible to find a solution to your problem... as others have pointed out already, it's quite unfeasible to load the whole list of combinations at once into memory... are you certain you need to add this to your dataframe?

Answer (score -1):

Sure it's possible! I also cannot conceive of why you would want to, but here you go...

```
def part(range1, range2):
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.Series(itertools.product(range1, range2))

range1gen = (range(i, min(i+ 100, 62977)) for i in range(0, 62977, 100))
range2gen = (range(0, 62977) for i in range(0, 62977, 100))
ser = dask.dataframe.from_map(part, range1gen, range2gen)
```

This produces 630 lazy partitions, 6297700 rows or about 100MB each, the first

```
>>> df.partitions[0].compute()
0               (0, 0)
1               (0, 1)
2               (0, 2)
3               (0, 3)
4               (0, 4)
              ...
6297695    (99, 62972)
6297696    (99, 62973)
6297697    (99, 62974)
6297698    (99, 62975)
6297699    (99, 62976)
```

(you will want to set the config to get these as tuples rather than strings: `dask.config.set({"dataframe.convert-string":  False})`)

Comment: I believe that's exactly what was requested @KellyBundy

Comment: Let's wait for the OP to specify. It would be simple to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As @KellyBundy stated, I don't wish to produce duplicate pairs such as (0,0), (1,1),... and if (0,1) was produced there's no need to produce (1,0) and so on, how can I fix this in your solution?

Comment: (sorry, didn't have time to update)